# How to find multiple elements in a page without having the content reread every time?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using

```
find_element_by_css_selector
```

to read approximately 400 variables from a web page and it's running very slow.

I profiled the code and noticed that for each **find_element** selenium is accessing **httplib**, and pretty sure it's re-reading the page - I think that's why things are running very slow.

Is there a way to tell selenium to read the page once and then use

```
 find_element_by_css_selector
```

just to parse the elements? (the page content is not going to change between reads)

Comment: Have you tried using `find_elements_by_css_selector` with multiple css selectors at once?

Comment: @YakupTürkan they all have different paths, I thought find_elements* can only be used if they share a path... if that's not true can you please share the syntax? can't seem to find in in the docs

Comment: [this is the selector syntax you want to use](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp)

example css selector to select divs with `item-container` and images with `item-image`

`div.item-container, img.item-image`

`driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.item-container, img.item-image')`

Comment: @YakupTürkan working great, thank you!

Comment: Post a link to a sample page and then describe what it is you are looking for. My guess is that you don't need 400 finds to get the data you want.

Comment: You likely don't want to use the above CSS selector syntax. It may speed things up but it will mix all the elements into one giant pile that you will then have to separate. The comma is an OR operator in CSS selectors so it will find any element that matches any of the locators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[W3 Schools CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[Chaining Css Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp)

> Selector for all div and all p elements `'div, p'`

[Selenium Python Readthedocs Locating Elements By CSS Selectors](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors)

> Use this when you want to locate an element by CSS selector syntax.

```
# find single div element with class item-container.
first_div = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.item-container') 

# find single img element with class item-image.
first_img = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img.item-image') 

# find multiple div elements with class item-container.
all_item_divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-container') 

# find multiple img elements with class item-container.
all_item_images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img.item-image')

# find multiple div elements with class item-container,
#   and img elements with class item-container.
all_item_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item-container, img.item-image')
```

Comment: I just profiled the code and suspect that even though this code batches multiple css selectors into 1 call, python's selenium package still makes separate calls for each selector path in the background :(